# Automating data management

Tags: sql, excel

This is a very general query. I'm an applied linguist and I run experiments in which I have participants generate data in an iterative "snowballing" fashion. This means that on day 1, they come in and contribute data; then on day 2, the data which they previously submitted becomes their new input. So if, on day one, a participant gets the word "cat" and responds with words like "dog", "kitten", "pet" etc., then on day 2 they would be asked to respond to "dog", "kitten", and "pet". Day 3, they respond to whatever their responses to those words were. Each iteration, they respond to an increasingly large number of words.

Up to now, with basically zero data science skills, I've been managing this process manually - i.e. every day I have to collect their responses from the previous day and move them into new files so that they become input for a new session; this includes randomising the delivery of the words, slicing up the number of words to be responded to so that each session contains a similar number of words and does not get unmanageably long, etc.

I'm sure that this can be handled much more effectively using CS tools; my question is, which one(s)? Currently I work in Excel and R; would something like SQL be a good option to handle this type of task? If I learned one new coding language/software tool to help me with this, what should it be?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Answers to this will be very subjective, often opinion based questions get closed off pretty quickly.

IMO it all depends on how much time you want to invest into a suitable solution, could could collect the data and store it into a database or flat files using Shiny and some built in R tools (perhaps to save to an SQL database or even csv files). 

If you want to learn something new, then perhaps look at Python. Perhaps building something in Flask and saving to some kind of database.

Comment: Find a CS, or rather CS-oriented student (e.g. from maths, physics, engineering departments) who will do the job for you as part of his / her university duties. In other words, my advice is to focus on *human* "tools", with everyone winning, 1 + 1 > 2.

Comment: If you wanted to use what you are already comfortable with then you could do it in excel VBA. And you could tie it to a SQL database if you needed a better database.